# Ionic 4: bgImage not showing up on StreamingAudioOptions

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am trying to create an app using ionic 4 that basically just streams an audio source from a remote server. Everything is working but I am still getting a black screen although I use bgImage in StreamAudioOptions. My bg image is located in src/assets/bg.png

I have tried the following references to the image:

```
/assets/bg.png
assets/bg.png
./assets/bg.png
../../assets/bg.png
```

Here is my code:

```
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingAudioOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media/ngx/';

playAudio() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.platform.is("cordova")) 
      {
        let options : StreamingAudioOptions = {
          bgImage: "/assets/bg.png",
          bgColor: "#fff",
          bgImageScale: "stretch",
          successCallback: () => 
          {
            console.log("Successfully played audio");
          },
          errorCallback: (e) => 
          {
            console.log(e);
          }
        };
        this.streaming.playAudio(this.mp3.url, options);
      } 
      else 
      {
        console.log("Must be on a mobile device to play!");
      }
  });
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by putting the ref as "www/assets/bg.png";

```
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingAudioOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media/ngx/';

playAudio() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.platform.is("cordova")) 
      {
        let options : StreamingAudioOptions = {
          bgImage: "www/assets/bg.png",
          bgImageScale: "stretch",
          successCallback: () => 
          {
            console.log("Successfully played audio");
          },
          errorCallback: (e) => 
          {
            console.log(e);
          }
        };
        this.streaming.playAudio(this.mp3.url, options);
      } 
      else 
      {
        console.log("Must be on a mobile device to play!");
      }
  });
}
```